# Alter name of trace in legend after plot is created (by package) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I'm wondering if there is any easy way to change the name in a legend (given using the colour aesthetic) on a ggplot after the plot is created. I know this feels a bit hacky and would normally be changed in the data or when the plot is created, but I want to change the label on a plot that is created by another package, and there's no option in the package to change it.

I could obviously copy the function and save my own version and change it, but I just want to change one thing so it seems neater if I can just do it afterwards.

Here is an example with some dummy data, basically I want to relabel the Mean and Median timeseries that come out of fasstr's `plot_daily_stats` to "Modelled Mean" and "Modelled Median" so they cannot be confused with the observed mean which I am manually adding.

```
    library(fasstr)
    library(tibble)
    library(ggplot2)

    #create some fake data
    df <- tibble(Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("1991-01-01"), as.Date("1997-12-31"), 
                                      by = "day"),
                     DayOfYear = as.numeric(format(Date, "%j")),
                     Value = runif(2557,0,1) + 50 + (cos((1/60)*DayOfYear)+4))

    obsdf <- tibble(Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("1900-01-01"), as.Date("1900-12-31"), 
                            by = "day"),
                 DayOfYear = as.numeric(format(Date, "%j")),
                 Value = runif(365,0,1) + 51 + (cos((1/60)*DayOfYear)+4))



    # create plot using fasstr package
    plt1<- fasstr::plot_daily_stats(df)

    # add my own trace. I also want to rename the trace "Mean" to 
     # "Modelled Mean" to avoid confusion (and same with Median) 
    plt1$Daily_Statistics +
      geom_line(data = obsdf, aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = "Observed Mean"))+
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black","blue"))
```

The names are given in `fasstr` as hard coded names:

```
daily_plots <- ... +
    ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes(y = Median, colour = "Median")) + 
    ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes(y = Mean, colour = "Mean"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hacking needed, just add labels to your manual scale.

```
plt1$Daily_Statistics +
  geom_line(data = obsdf, aes(x = Date, y = Value, colour = "Observed Mean"))+
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Modelled Mean","Modelled Median","Observed Mean"),
                      values = c("red", "black","blue"))
```

Comment: No problem. I didn't think of it at first either.